# Where else would it be be appropriate to ask the following question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here it is, asked 6 days ago;

[How many partial derivatives does a multivariate polynomial have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794755/how-many-partial-derivatives-does-a-multivariate-polynomial-have)

It isn't research-level (so, not appropriate for MO hence this post), but it hasn't been answered satisfactorily, either. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Add a bounty then.

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't know that mechanic existed until now.

Comment: @JohnMa Note that the OP currently has only 16 reputation points. The minimum reputation that can be offered in a bounty is 50, and the [privilege to set bounties](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) isn't granted until the user hits 75 reputation.

Comment: If you're at a university, ask someone in the Math Department. If you're in a city that has a university, ask someone in the Math Department.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Neither apply, unfortunately. Hence the original thread. I meant to ask "where else around this node of the internet", I should have been more specific. My apologies.

Comment: It's rather tersely stated; I find it hard to follow. The examples $\mathscr L(x)$ etc. are not obvious to me; it would make it a lot easier to understand the definition if you'd work out for at least one of those examples how you arrived at the result.

Comment: @joriki Thank you very much for your input, I will elaborate.

Comment: @joriki However, the motivation for the question does not need to be understood in order to comprehend the actual question.

Comment: @gxcc95: Although I do usually find that understanding the motivation helps in understanding the question, here I didn't mean the motivation; I really have a hard time understanding the definition and I suspect I'd understand it much better if I saw how you arrived at $\mathscr L(x)$.

Comment: I try to help to you when I open a BOUNTY, I don't understand well if your problem is easy/difficult, and I believe that the right is that I accept the answer for the bounty as the answer with more score. Was difficult to me earn and spent this reputation in your question, but I belive that your are much interesting in it, because you are in this site. I believe that I was wrong when I choose the message *to draw attention*, but now I have no reputation to comment it. Thanks to you and current answer.

Comment: @user243301 Thanks so much, that's very kind of you!

Comment: @joriki I have edited the original question to include an explanation of how $\mathscr{L}(x)$ is obtained.

Comment: @gxcc95: Thanks, it's clearer now.

Comment: You may ask at [AoPS](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community), in the suitable community.

Comment: Thanks @SubhadeepDey, I wasn't aware of this site, it looks promising.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, a meta question is scoped to the site itself. So whether or not it is allowed on MO or any other site is tangential to the conversation.

Assuming this Stack site follows the other Stack site models, you have the following options:

1. Edit - continue to update your post with your latest efforts and/or clarifications. This makes it easier to answer (which you obviously need if it isn't answered yet) and has the added benefit of bumping the post.
2. Bounty - if you have sufficient reputation, attach a bounty to the question. This will attract additional attention (it's in the bounty tab) and provide an additional incentive for solving it.
3. Share - each post (question and answer) has a share link. This link is tied to your account, so you'll actually get a badge if it's shared enough. (For 1k unique hits, there's even a gold badge!) You can leverage your social network to attract attention to the post. It may even bring in new members and what site doesn't want new experts coming in to assist in answering questions?
4. Wait - I know this is boring, but let's face it - six days isn't ALL that long. There are filters for unanswered questions that people use, and there is a badge for answering old questions so there are certainly reasons why people might answer it after a long time. I diamond mod another site and I see a lot of first posts are on old answers.
5. Answer it yourself - maybe you need additional training, or some offline help. But as you continue to work on the problem (and update your progress as per #1) you'll find you might actually solve it. If you do, don't forget to post your own answer - yours is just as valid as anyone else's!

Whatever you do, remain optimistic. The answer is out there somewhere!

Comment: Thank you very much! Great clarification/advice. I have been doing #1 quite a bit, will do #2 when I reach sufficient rep, #3 isn't so helpful for me personally as I have no social media account, actively doing #4, and working constantly working towards #5!

Comment: I gave a +1 for the fourth point in particular; patience is a rare commodity these days.